# phpMyAdmin Blank Settings Page

Tags: 13.04, server, apache2, phpmyadmin

I just installed phpMyAdmin on a clean Ubuntu Server 13.04 installation. Everything in the application works, except for the "Settings" page. This one page is blank when I click on it and when I attempt to view the source code there is nothing in the source. If I `cat` the file I can see that the file is not empty. The error log is not helpful - nothing is logged when attempting to view the page. How can I debug or fix this?